# connect to a server without shell initialization

Tags: ubuntu, authentication, ssh, digital-ocean, fish

I Installed fish shell on a VM then I stopped login in all users.
When i try to login via SSH on my terminal, I receive a permission denied as if I've entered a wrong password.

When I access the digital ocean web console, it shows that the password was correct, but there is an error

[image]

I know this error occurs because in the /etc/passwd file, fish was pointed to initialize but the system did not recognize it.

I just need some way to access the server without executing this file or just recover the files.

I tried some different aproaches using SSH and FTP but I failed.

**edit:**
I solved my problem using the digital ocean's recovery image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there an account that is still configured to use /bin/sh, /bin/bash, or some other shell that you can use to login as? If not your only option is to reboot to single user, or recovery, mode and use the linux VT console to fix the problem.

You've probably already learned this lesson but in the future after making such a change make sure you can login before exiting your current shell sessions and thus losing access to the system.